# Julia Struct to Dict

Tags: dictionary, struct, type-conversion, julia

can anybody help me. I just want to convert a Struct/Typ to a Dict in Julia.

```
  struct A
    A1::Int
    A2::Int
end
struct S
    atrr1::String
    attr2::String
    attr3::Int
    attr4::A
end
```

I need to convert an object from "S" to a dict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have an object `s`:

```
julia> s = S("a","b",3,A(4,5))
S("a", "b", 3, A(4, 5))
```

You can convert it to a `Dict` as:

```
julia> Dict(fieldnames(S) .=> getfield.(Ref(s), fieldnames(S)))
Dict{Symbol, Any} with 4 entries:
  :attr2 => "b"
  :attr4 => A(4, 5)
  :atrr1 => "a"
  :attr3 => 3
```

Note that `Dict`s have non fixed ordering. If you need to keep the same field order you could use `OrderedDict` from `OrderedCollections`.

You can also use comprehension (this actually looks to be 30% faster):

```
julia> Dict(key=>getfield(s, key) for key ∈ fieldnames(S))
Dict{Symbol, Any} with 4 entries:
  :attr2 => "b"
  :attr4 => A(4, 5)
  :atrr1 => "a"
  :attr3 => 3
```

Comment: than you sir a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> julia> Dict(key=>getfield(s, key) for key ∈ fieldnames(S))
> ```

If s is an instance of S, then you can also use:

```
function struct_to_dict(s)
  return Dict(key => getfield(s, key) for key in propertynames(s))
end
```

The difference is that you don't need to use the type name S.

Note: `fieldnames(typeof(s))` is slower than `propertynames(s)`!

Comment: This seems to be a response to the answer, not the original question?

Comment: Yes, I know, sorry, but I am new to Stackoverflow and I am not allowed to add comments to posts of others yet. Please, fell free to add what I have written as a comment to the first answer. Then I will delete this answer.